# Jmeter concurrency issue for a Thread of 7 Users

Tags: jmeter

I have 1 thread Group, Within that I have 5 HTTP Request calls. 1st HTTP Request returns a value & that value is used in rest 4 HTTP Requests. The Thread Group Set Up with Number of Thread (Users) : 7 & Ramp-Up period : 5 & Loop Count : infinite. When I run the thread group it breaks due to concurrency.

Example:

When User Thread 1 executes -> Request 1,

Thread 2 executes -> Request 2 (It expects a value from Request 1, Which has not happened for thread 2, Hence it breaks).

Please find the Jmeter SetUp Images below,

[Thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4vyT.jpg)

[HttpCookieManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cTKd.jpg)

I am new to Jmeter please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)
2. JMeter Variables are local for the thread (virtual user)

So there is no option that Thread 1 executes Sampler 1 and Thread 2 executes Sampler 2, all users will be executing all Samplers sequentially, it can be checked using [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum):

[image]

So my expectation is that either your extractor fails or Sampler 1 execution by Thread 2 fails somewhere somehow, check the requests and responses using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, the JMeter Variables using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.